# UIDatePicker not hiding

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, uidatepicker

I have created a UIDatePicker Programmatically and from a method i am setting the selected value into a textfield. But the value is not getting into the textfield and the picker is not hiding. Can anyone help me? My code is here

```
 datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 245, 320, 270)];
[self.view addSubview:datePicker];
datePicker.hidden=YES;
[datePicker release];
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy:MMMM:dd"];
self.dobtxt.text = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date];
[outputFormatter release];
[DoneBtnDate setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"OTdone.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
PickerDoneviewDate=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,210, 320, 35)];
PickerDoneviewDate.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
PickerDoneviewDate.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MFC_tab_01.png"]];
DoneBtnDate = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[DoneBtnDate addTarget:self action:@selector(DatePickerDone:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
DoneBtnDate.frame = CGRectMake(245,5, 70, 30);
[PickerDoneviewDate addSubview:DoneBtnDate];
[self.view addSubview:PickerDoneviewDate];
PickerDoneviewDate.hidden=YES;
}

   -(void)DatePickerDone:(id)sender
{
NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy:MMMM:dd"];

self.dobtxt.text = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date];
[datePicker release]; 
[datePicker setHidden:TRUE];

PickerDoneviewDate.hidden=YES;
[outputFormatter release];
}
```

code for adding text field

```
    dobtxt = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 120, 133, 26)];
    dobtxt.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
    dobtxt.background=[UIImage imageNamed: @"textbox_small.png"];
    dobtxt.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13];
    dobtxt.delegate = self;
    dobtxt.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    dobtxt.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter; 
    [scroll addSubview:dobtxt];
```

Comment: add self.dobtxt.text = @"test"; before [scroll addSubview:dobtxt]; check if the test will be there.

Comment: yes it shows test in that text field

Comment: how about replace "self.dobtxt.text = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date];" to "self.dobtxt.text = @"test""?

Comment: no its empty... even if i remove the self then also its empty

Comment: just NSLog(@"%@", self.dobtxt); in both two places to check if there are the same instance.

Comment: first nslog shows (null) second nslog is not displayed

Comment: show me the NSLog position in the code.

Comment: self.dobtxt.text = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date];
    NSLog(@"%@",self.dobtxt.text);
    NSLog(@"date:%@",[outputFormatter stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date]);
    [outputFormatter release];
 and    in the method self.dobtxt.text = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date];
    NSLog(@"%@",self.dobtxt.text);
   // [datePicker release];

Comment: plz tract the dobtxt in your project carefully, there must be something wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

datePicker is a property, it will be autoreleased. Plz delete

```
[datePicker release]; 


self.datePicker = [[[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 245, 320, 270)] autorelease];
[self.view addSubview:datePicker];
self.datePicker.hidden=YES;
//[datePicker release];
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy:MMMM:dd"];
self.dobtxt.text = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date];
[outputFormatter release];
[DoneBtnDate setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"OTdone.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
PickerDoneviewDate=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,210, 320, 35)];
PickerDoneviewDate.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
PickerDoneviewDate.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MFC_tab_01.png"]];
DoneBtnDate = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[DoneBtnDate addTarget:self action:@selector(DatePickerDone:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
DoneBtnDate.frame = CGRectMake(245,5, 70, 30);
[PickerDoneviewDate addSubview:DoneBtnDate];
[self.view addSubview:PickerDoneviewDate];
 self.PickerDoneviewDate.hidden=YES;
}

-(void)DatePickerDone:(id)sender
{
NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy:MMMM:dd"];

self.dobtxt.text = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date];
//[datePicker release]; 
[datePicker setHidden:TRUE];

PickerDoneviewDate.hidden=YES;
[outputFormatter release];
}
```

Comment: @priya have you comment the two release?

Comment: yes commented both lines still textfield is empty and datepicker is not hiding

Comment: @priya Is dobtxt an outlet? have you connected to the view?

Comment: dobtext is the textfield created programmatically. its inside a scroll  view... [scroll addSubview:dobtxt];

Comment: have you NSLog [outputFormatter stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date] to check is there any string output?

Comment: @priya have you released the dobtext somewhere?

Comment: @priya Then, could you plz post the code how you create the priya and set it?